# Make multiple API calls and return combined response in minimum time

Tags: java, multithreading, rest-assured

I have 10 health check URLs which are simply get service
I am hitting them in a loop like below

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
  Response response = given().when().relaxedHttpsValidation().get(url[i]);
   list.add(response);
  }
   return list;
```

Now the problem is it hits API in series and waiting for a response for all, I just want to hit all API in parallel but combine the result, I tried using threads but unable to get an idea on how to combine the response in case of multi-threading

Comment: Stick each call into a `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` then whack the whole lot into a [`CompletableFuture.allOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-). Or, if you want early termination behaviour, use a [`CompletionService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html).

Comment: Also, don’t use relaxed https validation - this disables https and turns the whole TLS process into a waste of CPU cycles.

Comment: You need to call it async, with the connection pooling, in case if you have the same host being called. This will improve the performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for your quick response i just want to share now how i achieved it

```
List responseList = new ArrayList();
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
exec.submit(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        String response = executeServiceCall(urlArray[i]);
        responseList.add(response);
     }
   });
} exec.shutdown();
 try {
exec.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
  LOGGER.error(e.toString());
}
 LOGGER.info("response list is " + responseList)
```

Answer (score 3):

If I am reading your question right I believe you want to make parallel calls and combine the results, and in that case I would suggest you to make use of TestNG. I had a similar requirement in the past and this [link](https://plagov.github.io/2018/09/13/running-multiple-parallel-requests-with-restassured-and-testng.html) helped me out

Here's a sample code

```
public class Parallel {

    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[] getURL() {
        return new Object[] { "https://reqres.in/api/users/1", "https://reqres.in/api/users/2",
                "https://reqres.in/api/users/3", "https://reqres.in/api/users/4", "https://reqres.in/api/users/5",
                "https://reqres.in/api/users/6" };
    }

    ArrayList<String> original = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Test(dataProvider = "getURL")
    public void stack(String url) {

        Response response = given().when().get(url);

        JsonPath js = response.jsonPath();

        String email = js.getString("data.email");

        original.add(js.getString("data.email"));
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void simple() {
        System.out.println("List : " + original);
    }

}
```

Just remove `(parallel = true)` to see how it works sequentially. I have extracted the email field from the response using JSONPath and added to the list

Don't forget to update the POM