# Multi threaded execution for RestAssured with TestNg or Cucumber

Tags: testng, rest-assured, cucumber-junit

Is it possible to achieve Multithreaded execution for RestAssured framework while using TestNG/Cucumber as Test frameworks.

I have seen a bug reported https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/534

Looks like its not resolved, the baseURI still seems to be static. Any one aware of possible solutions to run with either TestNG/Cucumber. I have a requirement to run my tests completely in parallel using restassured.

Comment: Check this and let me know - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62167334/3190953

Comment: Not sure how this will work for 100s of tests, coz you would be having same threads modifying the Restassure.BaseURI value simultaniously. Which is set in static context, so I believe its error prone

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is still relevant , but answering for any future reference.

`RestAssured` do have context of baseURI ( or basePath) as static. So when you run test cases for multiple API endpoints, it will cause a failure. As every time RestAssured.baseURI ( or RestAssured.basePath) is set one will be overwrite previous one.

I have solved it by creating a `ThreadLocal` variable and storing each thread API endpoint in this variable using `setter` method and then using this endpoint by calling `getter` method.

**Example**
Lets say I want to run two endpoints tests in parallel

1. localhost:8000/abc
2. localhost:8000/xyz

I have created a method to set endpoint as below:

```
RestAssured.baseURI  = "localhost:8000"

 public void verifyAPIEndpoint(String endPoint) {
        ThreadSafeBaseURI.setEndPoint(endPoint);
    }
```

Then to send API request I am using below method:

```
Response response;
public void sendGETRequest() {
        
        response = given()
                .basePath(ThreadSafeBaseURI.getEndPoint())
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .when()
                .get();
    }
```

Now Implementation of ThreadSafeBaseURI class is as  below:

```
public class ThreadSafeBaseURI {
    private static ThreadLocal<String> endPoint = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> null);


    public static void setEndPoint(String apiEndPoint) {
        endPoint.set(apiEndPoint);
    }

    public static String getEndPoint() {
        return endPoint.get();
    }
}
```